# Bottom taskbar lost often when to log in my debian

Tags: debian, lxde

```
uname -a
Linux MiWiFi-R3-srv 4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1~bpo9+1 (2020-06-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Recently, the bottom taskbar in often lost when to log in to my debian,  but not every time. How can I fix the issue?

[image]

The desktop environment is LXDE.

`df`:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1931680         0   1931680   0% /dev
tmpfs             391084      6204    384880   2% /run
/dev/sdb9      287320352 117568808 155086740  44% /
tmpfs            1955404    141952   1813452   8% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1955404         0   1955404   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0           128       128         0 100% /snap/anbox-installer/24
/dev/loop2         99328     99328         0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop3        382848    382848         0 100% /snap/anbox/186
/dev/loop1         98944     98944         0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/sda1      244197372   1149692 243047680   1% /mnt/shared
/dev/sdb2          98304     42725     55579  44% /boot/efi
/dev/loop5        515968    515968         0 100% /var/xdroid/common/rootfs
tmpfs             391080         8    391072   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs             391080         0    391080   0% /run/user/65534
```

`cat  ~/.xsession-errors`:

```
Xsession: X session started for debian at Mon Dec 14 13:01:24 CST 2020
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/debian/.Xauthority
localuser:debian being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
OpenGL version: 3.
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=debian
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/debian
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=LXDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=debian
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_US.utf8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.utf8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=LXDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/debian/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm/data/debian
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=LXDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/debian
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
** Message: main.vala:102: Session is LXDE
** Message: main.vala:103: DE is LXDE
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-punc.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-fullwidth-char.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-notificationitem.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkb.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-unicode.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-lua.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-sunpinyin.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-autoeng.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xim.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-ipc.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-googlepinyin.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-remote-module.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-spell.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-clipboard.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-dbus.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-freedesktop-notify.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-kimpanel-ui.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-table.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-classic-ui.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-x11.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin-enhance.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-quickphrase.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkbdbus.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-chttrans.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-keyboard.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-imselector.conf
(INFO-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-vk.conf
** Message: main.vala:134: log directory: /home/debian/.cache/lxsession/LXDE
** Message: main.vala:135: log path: /home/debian/.cache/lxsession/LXDE/run.log
(ERROR-2905 /build/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/ime.c:432) fcitx-keyboard-cm-mmuock already exists
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `df` (you might be running out of space, wherever lxde tries to write data). Also, check the last lines in `~/.xsession-errors` and see if they help find the issue. If you cannot get meaningful information from them, please add them to your question. Also, you say `often` but, is it reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LXPanel provides the bottom bar on LXDE. According to your screenshot, the panel is not "lost": it did not crash or segfault. It is just empty: it did not load any widgets. I was able to recreate the appearance of what you have in your image by removing background and all widgets from the panel. There seem to be no relevant bug reports on the Debian and LXDE bug trackers.

As you say that it fails only sometimes, you can restart the panel instead of restarting the computer, to get the widgets back faster:

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

Considering that according to your screenshot the LXPanel is running, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut, which is handled by LXPanel in LXDE, should work and bring you the command prompt where you can type that command in.

You could try restarting the panel many times in a row. If restarting does cause the panel to lose its widgets sometimes, then the problem must be with loading the panel's configurations from the profile.

You can remove the profile to start with fresh default configurations to see if it solves your issue. Unless you changed it name, the default profile should be `LXDE` on Debian. (It is different of Lubuntu.)

```
$ mv ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-backup
$ lxpanelctl restart
```

If you've made any changes to your panel, which you would like to keep, you will need to add them manually again. It makes sense to add them back gradually to see whether any particular configuration or widget is causing the problem.

LXPanel is version 0.10.0 on a clean install of Debian 10. If your version is different, there may be a problem with upgrading the system.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the process that starts the taskbar has crashed. If you can't bring up a context menu using the right-click/center-click or even draw a selection box (its been awhile since I used LXDE) your window manager probably crashed, background image I believe is handled differently. You might be able bring up a run bar, and execute 'xterm' and then relaunch the window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is running out of memory:

```
df  |  grep  100%

Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0           128       128         0 100% /snap/anbox-installer/24
/dev/loop2         99328     99328         0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop3        382848    382848         0 100% /snap/anbox/186
/dev/loop1         98944     98944         0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/loop5        515968    515968         0 100% /var/xdroid/common/rootfs
```

Remove snapd:

```
sudo umount $(mount | grep snap | awk '{print $3}')
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/snapd
sudo rm -rvf /var/snap

Remove any unit files that try to mount snaps from /var/lib/snapd/snaps to /var/lib/snapd/snap at boot.

sudo find /etc/systemd/system -name "snap-.mount" -delete
sudo find /etc/systemd/system -name "snap.*.service" -delete
```

Reboot to test, i find that sometimes taskbar still lost .

```
 df  |grep 100%
/dev/loop5        515968    515968         0 100% /var/xdroid/common/rootfs
```

Find service at boot.

```
sudo  systemd-analyze blame | grep  xdroid
xdroid-service.service
```

Disable the service.

```
sudo systemctl disable  xdroid-service.service
```

I haven't had my taskbar disappear for several days since then.

Comment: Interesting to see a connection between xdroid and your task bar!